# AngularJS - check if fields of model are the same with the initial values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

If I have the following object `$scope.object1` which looks something like this:

```
{
 "firstName": "Name"
 "lastName": "Name"
 "startingDate": "08/Nov/2016"
 "endingDate": "16/Dec/2016"
 "description": "asd"
}
```

And I have a form which takes those values from backend and uses them on the input fields for date and description.
The fields are editable so changing `startingDate` in the form field will change starting date in `object1`.

I need to display some content based on the initial values of `$scope.object1` are the same with the values after submitting the form.

With other words, if nothing has changed.

How can I save the initial values of `object1` and compare them with the values after modifying the form?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `angular.copy()` to store the object before it is edited and `angular.equals()` to compare it with the modified version after it is edited

```
var objectBackup = angular.copy($scope.object1);
//...
if(angular.equal(objectBackup, $scope.object1) === false) {
    //The object has been modified
}
```

Comment: But if my model changes, this will not evaluate to false even before submitting the form?

Comment: take a look at what `angular.equal()` does https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals

Comment: I understand how equals works now, thank you. But I have another problem. When I submit the form, the function in which I used angular.copy is called again and the condition is still true. How can I bypass this?

Answer (score 0):

Angular have two different way to check changes in your objects.

**1- checking if the form change**
if you use the object like ng-model in a form you can use the property $dirty.

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="processForm()" class="p-lg">
    //inputs
    <input type="text" id="firstName" ng-model="object1.firstName">
   //...
</form>
```

Controller

```
...
var objCopy = angular.copy($scope.object1);
...
$scope.processForm = function(){
  if($scope.myForm.$dirty){
    console.log('some field in the object change');
    //you can check the specific variable that you want and use the old one
  }
}
...
```

**2- watch a object or specific key**(that will be evaluate in every single digest)

```
//controller
     $scope.$watch('object1.firstName', function(newVal, oldVal){
            console.log('firstName change',oldVal, newVal );
        }, true);
```

Comment: Please, keep in mind It is always recommended to use any other possible variant rather that using a *watcher* in angular, since this has a direct impact on the app performance. I think, here there are other possible solution instead of using a *watcher*

Comment: I agree, but sometimes it's useful use the watch, depends a lot of your scope. but I think the first option combined with the copy object it's better than compare always a object. I will modify my answer